# Using prefix_default_language=False disable javascript translations

Tags: django, internationalization, django-urls, django-staticfiles, django-i18n

I have implemented javascript translations, following exactly the documentation.
It works perfectly when I use prefix_default_language=True in my i18n_patterns fonction.
But when prefix_default_language is set to False, all of the translations in javascript code are not working :

```
document.write(gettext("this is to be translated"))
```

Is this a know issue? Is there something Im missing?